# How to stop textareas looking different on two different versions of chrome?

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, input

Cross-browser testing gives me a headache at the best of times, but this one has really stumped me.
I developed my website in Google Chrome **(and on a Mac)**, and have recently updated the search function and re-styled the search input area.

I noticed that when I did cross-browser checks in Internet Explorer, the text in the search input in the top right-hand corner of the website was not positioned in the same way as it is on chrome.

In my version of Chrome, the text is 10px away from the left edge of the box, so it sits in there nicely. On Internet Explorer, however, it is right up against the egde of the box.

Here's the issue - When I opened my website in Chrome **on a PC** the text in the input was positioned in the same way as it appears in IE.

I assume this is because Chrome on my Mac is a different version than that that is on the PC. Can anybody help me solve this so that the text sits nicely across these browsers?

You can view my website here at http://tinyurl.com/8uaajmz

Thanks in advance everybody!

Answer (score 0):

Your CSS rule for #search_bar_2 has an _ at the beginning of the name change it to:

```
text-indent:10px !important;
```

and you're fine. Not a cross browser issue it's a typo issue.

Comment: Thanks for the reply Rick, I really appreciate it. However, unfortunately this doesn't solve the issue I'm having. I've taken out the _text-indent (which I initially put in as a IE hack) and the search box is still displaying differently on Chrome on my mac than how it does on Chrome on the PC.

The PC is not showing any indent, whereas there is a 10px indent on my Mac version of Chrome.

Comment: No problem. If you wouldn't mind accepting it as the answer when you have a moment that would be great.